# Html file content not shown correctly when using "echo" in Wordpress widget

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, d3.js

I added a custom widget class to my wordpress page:

```
<?php


class CorsiTestWidget extends WP_Widget
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct(
            'corsi_test_widget',
            'Corsi Test Widget');
    }

    public function widget($args, $instance)
    {
        $htmlFilePath = plugin_dir_path(CORSI_TEST_PLUGIN_FILE) . 'assets/corsi-test.html';
        echo file_get_contents($htmlFilePath);
    }

    public function form($instance)
    {
        return parent::form($instance); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
    }

    public function update($new_instance, $old_instance)
    {
        return parent::update($new_instance, $old_instance); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
    }
}

function corsi_test_register_widget() {
    register_widget('CorsiTestWidget');
}

add_action('widgets_init', 'corsi_test_register_widget');
```

My widget() method is trying to load contents of corsi-test.html file, this file contains javascript and html as follows:

```
<div id='main-container'></div>

<script src="http://libs.wl369.com/libs/d3/3.3.13/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-transform/1.0.4/d3-transform.min.js">
</script>
<script>
// code to show some blocks on the screen
</script>
```

The problem is, contents of the html file don't seem to appear on page when I'm "echo"ing them, to be more precise, the javascript inside html file is not executing correctly, so there is nothing to see in the widget. I tried putting some html (no js) in file and it worked, but I need the js to execute, too.

Any idea what causes the problem? and also:

1. when I use die(file_get_contents($htmlFilePath)) instead of echo, html and js are shown correctly, but I don't want to die them because I need php to continue running.
2. This problem occurs when deploying code on website. On my local machine, everything works fine and "echo" prints contents of html file + javascript functions inside it.

Comment: Check the browser console for errors. Are you accessing the website using `https` or `http` on the real server? If it's `https`, then you'll probably need to change `src="http://libs.wl369.com/..."` to `https://libs.wl369.com/..."`. Browsers tend to block non-`https` requests when the site is under `https` so any JS code that depends on that js file being loaded will fail. When working locally, you usually use `http`, which is why it can work there.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I tried using https://.... but it did not work, also there is no error on my console. I traced the code and apparently the "window.onload" event (called somewhere in js script in corsi-test.html file) is not triggered when I echo html file contents, that's why I don't see anything on the page.

Comment: The problem was the "window.onload()" event. Somehow it isn't triggered on website. I tried adding function to load event, using "obj.attachEvent("on"+event, fn);" and it worked.